# Communicating with an iOS device connected to an OSX VirtualBox VM

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, virtualbox, calabash-ios

I am a tester writing cucumber test scripts using a Calabash/Ruby solution.

Here is my setup.  I have two iOS devices plugged into a mac-mini.  I have Xcode running and connected to a physical device.  I also have an Oracle Virtualbox VM running on it that has another copy of Xcode running and that VM has another physical iOS device connected to it.

My dilemma is this.  What I need is to write one test scenario that can test communication like calling and text between the two...so from within that test scenario I need to find a way to switch between the two devices.

I have been able to successfully write cucumber tests for Android doing this by adding special tags in the app_installation_hooks file. I referenced this [link](http://blog.lesspainful.com/2013/03/15/Testing-Multiple-Android-Apps/).

I have an idea it involves redefining the BUNDLE_ID, DEVICE_TARGET, and DEVICE_ENDPOINT every time I switch to a device, but I'm not sure how to write that if that is the solution.

I'm currently executing just one of my tests by calling 'bundle exec cucumber' which I can do on both machines (phsycial and virtual) individually.